# Как картинку из памяти (<class 'bytes'>) переконвертировать в base64 на Python

Tags: python, base64

Я получил картинку в байтовом виде.

```
<class 'bytes'>
b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x0.........
```

Чисто теоретически ее могу сохранить на компьютер в текстовом формате и потом открыть как текст и передать, а картинку удалить. Но это не вариант.
Вопрос: Как сконвертировать картинку (полученные байтовые данные) в формат base64?

Comment: `image_text = base64.b64encode(image_bytes).decode('ascii')`

Comment: Получается, что надо байто-код сначала сохранить как текст, а потом открыть и читать его как текст, чтобы отправить в кодировку. По сути получается то же самое, что я и писал выше. Я просто ищу перекодировку сразу из байтокода, чтобы не сохранять файл на устройстве.

Comment: @АлексейБелкин если вам нужно получить картинку в b64 - вариант выше верен. Если вам этот вариант почему-то не подходит, то объясните, почему и что вы хотите.

Comment: `Я просто ищу перекодировку сразу из байтокода, чтобы не сохранять файл на устройстве.` - на устройстве файл не сохраняется, все данные держатся в оперативной памяти.

Comment: @GrAnd, Спасибо!